# Is there really no simple form for the projection onto the positive part of the hyperboloid model?

Tags: convex-optimization, conic-sections, closed-form, lagrange-multiplier, projection

Consider the "positive part" of the [hyperboloid model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_space)
$$
\mathbb H_+^d := \{ (x_1, \ldots, x_d, x_{d + 1}) \in \mathbb R^{d} \times \mathbb R_{> 0}: \sum_{k = 1}^{d} x_k^2 = x_{d + 1}^2 - 1 \}.
$$
How does the [orthogonal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projection) $\text{proj}_{\mathbb H_+^d}(p)$ of a point $p \in \mathbb R^{d + 1}$ onto $\mathbb H_+^d$ look like?

**My work.**
We have $\text{proj}_{\mathbb H_+^d}(p) = \text{argmin}_{x \in \mathbb H_+^d} \| p - x \|_2^2$, where $\| \cdot \|_2$ denotes the Euclidean norm.
Setting up the Lagrange problem
$$
\min_{x \in \mathbb R^{d + 1}} \| p - x \|_2^2 + \lambda \left( \sum_{k = 1}^{d} x_k^2 - x_{d + 1}^2 + 1\right) + \mu x_{d + 1}
$$
for some Lagrange multipliers $\mu,\lambda \in \mathbb R$ yields the optimality condition (setting the gradient with respect to $x$ to zero)
$$
x_k = \frac{p_k}{1 - \lambda} \; \forall k \in \{ 1, \ldots, d \}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
x_{d + 1} = \frac{p_{d + 1}}{1 + \lambda} + \mu.
$$
Plugging this into the objective and trying to solve for $\lambda$ yields an equation which is quartic in $\lambda$ and [has many and very complicated solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+%281+%2B+x%29%5E2+a+-+%281+-+x%29%5E2+b+%3D+-%281-x%5E2%29%5E2+for+x).

Is there another way to find this projection?